# Why is this the output using pointing c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't know why this code gives the result it does.  I thought the pointer `p` should be the address of `str` and the output should always be the address in the while loop.  Why is the result is the real value of `str` like that?

```
char str[] = "we are poor students";//这是一个字符串
cout<<str<<endl;
char *p = str;
while (*p != '\0')
{
    cout << p<<endl;
    p++;
}
return 0;
```

This is the result it gives:

> ```
> we are poor students
> we are poor students
> e are poor students
>  are poor students
> are poor students
> re poor students
> e poor students
>  poor students
> poor students
> oor students
> or students
> r students
>  students
> students
> tudents
> udents
> dents
> ents
> nts
> ts
> s
> ```

Comment: Don't post links to results as images. Put it *in* the question as *text*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl ok, thank you

Answer (score 9):

There is a special overload for `const char*` to display c-string content, to print the address, cast it to `void*`:

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(p) << endl;
```